# Binary image decoding in R with Tensorflow

Tags: r

I am running the following code to read in [this binary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgW9d.jpg) (mask):

```
msk = tf$io$read_file("image/mask/") %>% tf$image$decode_image(channels=1) %>% tf$image$convert_image_dtype(dtype=tf$uint8)
```

Since it is a binary image I expect to observe only values 255 and 0 in my image array, but when I run `summary(unique(as.vector(as.array(msk))))` I get an output, indicating that there are values other than 0's and 255's:

```
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
0.000   1.957  94.426 122.135 252.176 255.000
```

Further, running, for isntance, `head(as.data.frame(table(as.vector(as.array(msk)))), 10)` yields:

```
Var1   Freq
1                     0 685464
2  0.000226974487304688      3
3  0.000257492065429688      6
4  0.000314712524414062      3
5  0.000577926635742188      3
6  0.000629425048828125      3
7  0.000988006591796875      3
8   0.00111198425292969      3
9   0.00136375427246094      3
10  0.00149345397949219      3
```

And then `tail(as.data.frame(table(as.vector(as.array(msk)))), 10)` returns:

```
    Var1  Freq
16075 254.998428344727     3
16076 254.998443603516     3
16077 254.998504638672     3
16078  254.99853515625     3
16079 254.999160766602     3
16080 254.999221801758     3
16081 254.999450683594     3
16082 254.999633789062     3
16083 254.999694824219     3
16084              255 52014
```

Do I get something wrong? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where does it say that there are other values than 0 and 255? You can have a mean of 24.xx and only values of 0 and 255. Additionally, could you provide a MWE or the picture you are importing? For the MWE see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @tester, thank you for fast reply. I absolutely agree with your comment regarding the mean value. However, when I study my image array, I observe values other than 0's and 255's. I have corrected my question taking into consideration your point, added another summary statistic to better demonstrate my concerns and attached the image.